# Zend - changing image URL path for deployment

Tags: php, zend-framework, amazon-s3, zend-config

The title might be confusing as I'm not sure myself on how to explain this. I'm sure its a pretty simple solution.

I'm moving all my static images,css,js to S3 - so now they can be accessed via

Egs:

```
http://files.xyz.com/images/logo.gif
http://files.xyz.com/images/submit_button.gif
http://files.xyz.com/style/style.css
http://files.xyz.com/js/jquery.js
```

files.xyz.com is a CNAME pointing to files.xyz.com.s3.amazonaws.com

Now in my Zend layout and views - I'm accessing these with the full URL
egs

`<img src="http://files.xyz.com/images/logo.gif"/>`

My concern is when I'm testing on localhost - I dont want the data to be fetched from S3 but from my local hard disk

So I want to do something like this. In my application.ini - I should be able to specify

```
resources.frontController.imageUrl = http://localhost
```

And when I'm deploying - simply change that to

```
resources.frontController.imageUrl = http://files.xyz.com
```

```
And access it in the view like
<img src="<?php echo $this->imageUrl;?>/images/logo.gif"/>
```

What is the best approach to handling this
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a view helper

```
public function imageUrl()
    {
        $config = Zend_Registry::get('config');
        if($config->s3->enabled){
            return $config->s3->rootPath; 
        }else{
            return $this->view->baseUrl(); 
        }
    }
```

In appilication.ini

```
s3.enabled        = 1
s3.rootPath       = https://xxxxx.s3.amazonaws.com
```

You can call like this

```
<img src="<?php echo $this->imageUrl();?>/images/logo.gif"/>
```

So you can enable/disable the s3 easily.

Answer (score 0):

Try the [baseUrl view helper](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.initial.baseurl). Specify the URL in your application.ini like this:

```
[production]
resources.frontController.baseUrl = "http://files.xyz.com"
```

Then in your views:

```
<img src="<?php echo $this->baseUrl('images/someimage.jpg'); ?>">
```

Comment: Thanks Eugene. I thought about that but isn't the baseUrl set to - in my example http://xyz.com - so if I change it to http://files.xyz.com - it will get effected in other places where its expecting http://xyz.com right

Comment: Honestly I am not sure whether that will affect URLs generated by the url view helper such as `$this->view-url(array('index', 'index'))`. If it causes a problem you may want to just define your own view helper that functions similarly to the baseUrl helper.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are setting your `APPLICATION_ENV` and using environment-specific sections in your `application/configs/application.ini` file, then a combination of your idea and the view helper idea seems the way to go.

In `application/configs/application.ini`:

```
[production]

cdn.baseUrl = "http://files.zyz.com"

[development]

cdn.baseUrl = "http://mylocalvirtualhost/assets/img"
```

Then a view helper:

```
class My_View_Helper_CdnBaseUrl extends Zend_View_Helper_Abstract
{
    protected static $defaultBase = '';

    protected $base;

    public function cdnBaseUrl($file = '')
    {
        return rtrim($this->getBase(), '/') . '/' . ltrim($file, '/');
    }

    public static function setDefaultBase($base)
    {
        self::$defaultBase = $base;
    }

    protected function getBase()
    {
        if (null === $this->base){
            $this->base = self::$defaultBase;
        }
        return $this->base;
    }
}
```

In `application/Bootstrap.php`:

```
protected function _initCdn()
{
    $options = $this->getOptions();
    My_View_Helper_CdnBaseUrl::setDefaultBase($options['cdn']['baseUrl']);
}
```

Thenm usage in a view-script is as follows:

```
<img src="<?= $this->cdnBaseUrl('root/relative/path/to/img.jpg') ?>" alt="Some image">
```

Of course, you will need to add `autloadernamespaces` and view-helper prefix paths to match your own namespacing, etc.